# open write review page using SKStore​Review​Controller with query parameters "action=write-review"

Tags: ios, swift, review, skstorereviewcontroller

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skstorereviewcontroller/2851536-requestreview

> Apple document suggest to automatically open a page on which users can write a review in the
> App Store, append the query parameter action=write-review to your
> product URL.

I want to redirect the user to write a comment page of the app on the app store.
I am new to iOS please guide me to achieve this functionality.

Thank you.

Comment: Which functionality?  Using `SKStoreReviewController` or putting a link in your app's settings page?

Comment: SKStoreReviewController - but default it shows popup as "enjoying app?" with 5 starts showing submit option.But I want to redirect user to write review as and when apple shows this dialogue.Apple documeted as you can pass "action=write-review" parameter but I am not able to find any function for that in SKStoreReviewController.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here i what i am using

```
let appID = "Your App ID on App Store"
let urlStr = "itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/app/id\(appID)?action=write-review" 
if let url = URL(string: urlStr), UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url) {
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
    } else {
        UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
    }
}
```